# Myfaces tomahawk file upload "Browse" button styling

Tags: html, css, jsf, twitter-bootstrap, tomahawk

I have problem with file upload button styling, I am using tomahawk file upload, so no one style can be change generated browse button.

How I can apply styles for Browse button? I have Twitter bootstrap but no one style affect on it.

```
   <t:inputFileUpload id="openssme"  value="#{imageUploadBean.upFile}"  styleClass="btn"
                                                       title="+ Add pictures from computer" 
                                                       required="true"
                                                       accept="image/*"  size="20" storage="file"/>
```

Comment: Note: problem isn't specific to JSF/Tomahawk. Problem is specific to the produced HTML element itself, the `<input type="file">`. In other words, you'd have had exactly the same problem when saving the JSF-generated HTML output into a plain `.html` file and reopening it. You will have more chance in getting answers if you remove the irrelevant JSF part and base your question on its generated HTML representation instead (and, you'll discover that search engines will yield so much more helpful results if you alter the search keywords based on that).

Comment: Thanks, already I understand it:(